# Is it possible to buld a CLI app using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I'm looking to write a CLI app. My app is not suited for a web app. I'm running Ruby 2.2.2 on OSX and Ubuntu.

**Can I use Rails to build an app that is strictly interacting via the CLI (not via HTTP)?**

Comment: Why would you want to? You can pull the non-web parts you need into a CLI app. That said: the ability to interact over an API is nothing to sneeze at, even if you don't realize it yet.

Comment: You can, but you're wasting a huge amount of Rails' functionality, which is web-based, so why? You can easily build CLI apps with DB integration using an ORM such as [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net), and [cherry-pick parts of ActiveSupport](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) if needed, and end up with an app that is much smaller.

Comment: As @DaveNewton was saying, building a backend that uses a REST interface via HTTP could be done with Rails. Then the command-line clients could use HTTP clients to talk to the back end. It depends on if you want a distributed system or not. If you're new to Ruby, then jumping into Rails is a steep learning curve, because Rails takes advantage of a lot of Ruby's deep magic; Looking at that code without understanding what is happening can leave you bewildered. A straight Ruby CLI app tends to be much simpler and easier to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely use a Rails app. That's the short answer.

As Controllers and Views are likely unneeded in a CLI application, a large chunk of the Rails framework will be obviated entirely. But Rails models, ActiveRecord, Arel and the database management aspects are really powerful. How nice it would be to just leverage those.

*SHOULD* you? Outside the scope of your question and highly dependent on your requirements & personal preference, which I'm not privy to, of course.

Comment: It depends on what sort of a command-line app you're creating. If it's literally a series of commands used by the shell, MVC doesn't always apply. If it's something interactive with [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) it might have a UI and MVC comes back into play, but not the Rails one.

Comment: Oh, definitely. I was assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that the reason the OP was interested in using Rails was for the database stuff. I recently wrote a CLI that lives inside our Rails app space so my thinking might have been biased unconsciously.